# In the Wordpress dynamic sidebar: any loop after the third loop does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, sidebar

I have a custom post type (single-result.php) and an associated custom sidebar (sidebar-results.php). In the sidebar I have four loops using Advanced Custom Fields:

1. A link to "splits", which grabs a url that's been pasted into an ACF text field (it's an external link)
2. A link to "routes", same as #1
3. A link to a related results page, which grabs a link using ACF's relationship field
4. A link to a related series results page, same as #3

What is really strange is that the first three items will always return their links, but the fourth item will fail and show the "else" text. Even if I mix up the order of all the items, it is always the fourth one. If I add a fifth item, it is the fourth and fifth that do not work. So strange!

Any ideas?

Here is the sidebar code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs sidebar md-mrg-top"> <!-- begin sidebar RIGHT -->
    <div class="sidebar-widgets">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'results' ) ): ?>


    
     <div class="text-center">
      <!-- WinSplits link, from ACF text field -->
      <p class="md-mrg-top">
      <?php
   $key = 'winsplits_link_results';
   $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
   if($themeta == '') {
   echo 'Check back soon for splits';
   }
   else {
    echo '<a href="';
    echo the_field('winsplits_link_results');
    echo '">WinSplits';
    echo '</a>';
   }
   ?>
   </p>


   <!-- RouteGadget link, from ACF text field -->
   <p>
   <?php
   $key = 'routegadget_link_results';
   $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
   if($themeta == '') {
   echo 'Check back soon for routes';
   }
   else {
    echo '<a href="';
    echo the_field('routegadget_link_results');
    echo '">RouteGadget';
    echo '</a>';
   }
   ?>
   </p>


   <!-- Link to related season standings results page, from ACF relationship field -->
   <p>
            <?php

                $posts = get_field('related_season', $post->ID);
                
                if( $posts ) {

                    foreach( $posts as $post ):
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
                        echo get_the_title();
                        echo '</a>';
                    endforeach;
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                } else {
                    echo "No related related_season";
                }
            ?>
            </p>
            
   

   <p> <!-- Link to team or individual results page, from ACF relationship field -->
            <?php

                $posts = get_field('team_or_individual', $post->ID);
                
                if( $posts ) {

                    foreach( $posts as $post ):
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
                        echo get_the_title();
                        echo '</a>';
                    endforeach;
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                } else {
                    echo "No team/indi link";
                }
            ?>
            </p>

            



  </div>


     <?php endif; ?> <!-- belongs to dynamic sidebar -->
 </div>
</div> <!-- close sidebar right -->
```

Comment: When I var_dump the fourth item, it returns bool(false).

Comment: I found not an answer, but a work-around. Instead of having two separate relationship fields, I combined them into one relationship field that supports both the links I need.